# loopback create user by admin but update profile by user

Tags: javascript, node.js, acl, loopbackjs, loopback

I try using below model to manage my user managment in a LoopBack 3 API:

```
{
  "name": "Employee",
  "plural": "Employees",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "ClearBaseAcls": true
  },
  "hidden": [
    "password",
    "verificationToken"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "family": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls":
    [ { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$everyone", "permission": "DENY" },
      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$everyone", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "login" },
      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$everyone", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "logout" },
      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$everyone", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "confirm" },

      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "admin", "permission": "ALLOW" },

      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "findById" },
      { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "updateAttributes" }
    ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and Also use this mixis: (ClearBaseAcls)

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');

function slugify(name) {
  name = name.replace(/^[A-Z]+/, s => s.toLowerCase());
  return name.replace(/[A-Z]/g, s => '-' + s.toLowerCase());
}

module.exports = (Model) => {
  const configFile = path.join('./common/models/', slugify(Model.modelName) + '.json');
  const config = appRoot.require(configFile);

  if (!config || !config.acls) {
    console.error('ClearBaseAcls: Failed to load model config from', configFile);
    return;
  }

  Model.settings.acls.length = 0;
  config.acls.forEach(r => Model.settings.acls.push(r));
};
```

Now anything is OK for me.
Only **admin** can **create** new user and do anything.
**$everyone** only can **login**, **logout** and **confirm** account.
But I have some issue with **$owner** part. Because of user creation done by admin now 'admin' is owner of any other user and nobody can't use **findById** or **updateAttributes** (update profile).

---

**Update:**

I test again and new users can use findById ( GET /Employees/{id} ) (I don't know why it's worked but it's all we need) BUUUUT another issue, new users can't use updateAttributes ( PATCH /Employees/{id} ) and show bellow error:

```
Authorization Required
```

Why **findById** ( GET /Employees/{id} ) worked??
Why **updateAttributes** ( PATCH /Employees/{id} )??
Why this two not same?
Can you guide me how to fix this? I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Are you using the same ID the user is connected to? $owner is only possible to subjects the $owner is connected directly through in a relation. For updateAttributes to work it has to be the employe-id the user is attached to.

Comment: Hi @Undrium, Yes I'm using the same ID. I think it's a bug. Please see this issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a working solution:
I change this line:

```
{ "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "updateAttributes" }
```

to below line:

```
{ "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "patchAttributes" }
```

I found it in [this file](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/common/models/user.json#L65).

It's a documentation issue [here](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user) where `updateAttributes` changed to `patchAttributes` but it's not changed in docs.

Comment: What is the point of redefining exactly the same ACL than the one already defined in the User model ? (it was the point of my answer if you had read it). Also, as soon as there will be a new 3.X release you will hit this bug again, since it's been fixed in [3.X latest](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/3.x-latest/common/models/user.json#L76).

Comment: Because I want override all User permission with ClearBaseAcls. Please read question completely before vote.

Comment: Please explain your question better then, because what this mixin is doing is not understandable without the config files it's calling. Now you should read my comment better as well, because the link I provided clearly shows that this answer is wrong, and you will encounter a bug in the future. Suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your ACL currently only the owner of the record is able to update/delete any data, in order to allow another user you must change the ACL updateAttributes the principalId to $authenticated.

```
"acls":
[ 
  { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$authenticated", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "updateAttributes" }
],
```

But this approach let to any authenticated user change any other profile so to prevent this action you can add a [beforeRemote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html) look for the current userId and the profile userId to compare them and allow if this values match.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Can you guide me about beforeRemote hook too? I don't know how we can check userId in hook.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem here, this acl rule is already defined in loopback with [base User model](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user). Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: ACL with $authenticated always return "Authorization Required" error

Answer (score 1):

> But I have some issue with $owner part. Because of user creation done by admin now 'admin' is owner of any other user

If you are using the endpoint `POST /Employees` to create new users this is not true. Admin is not the $owner. See the [loopback doc](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html):

> To qualify a $owner, the target model needs to have a belongsTo relation to the User model and property matching the foreign key of the target model instance.  The check for $owner is only performed for a remote method that has ‘:id’ on the path, for example, GET /api/users/:id.

Also, you are redefining findById and updateAttributes acls, but [they are already defined in loopback](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#user) as part of the base user. So you can remove those 2 lines.

```
 { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "findById" },
 { "principalType": "ROLE", "principalId": "$owner", "permission": "ALLOW", "property": "updateAttributes" }
```

Now, you're having weird behavior with ACLS and you are using a custom mixin that messes with the acls registration. I don't understand precisely what this mixin is supposed to do but my best guess is that the issue is coming from it.

Remove this file from your project, restart your server and test without it. Should fix your problems.